# What is the difference between 2 ways to set arguments of fragment

Tags: android

I want to pass a data object to `Fragment`, here are two ways to do this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private Serializable way1;

    private Serializable way2;

    public void setDataWay1(Serializable way1) {
        this.way1 = way1;
    }

    public void setDataWay2(Serializable way2) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putSerializable("data", way2);
        setArguments(data);
    }
}
```

So, what is the difference between the 2 ways? Sometimes, way1 may cause `NullPointerException`,why? If I want to pass a `OnClickListener` to `Fragment`, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both methods can set the appropriate data to your fragment for first time initialization. Note that fragments will be recreated and destroyed by the system (for example on screen rotation). When that happens the system will not really call the setter way (method 1) hence, it will be a giant FAIL. Therefore, it is recommended to use the `setArguments()` way.

Comment: Up voted for adding information about configuration changes.